# Functional dependency and normalization for a relation schema

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization

If I have relation schema R(A, B, C, D, E) with functional dependencies:
AB->C, CD->E, C->A, E->D, then what are the keys for R and what is the normal form of R? How can I achieve a higher normal form?

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14659070/562459) should help you identify all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

A possible set of keys would be (A, B, D).

A normal form would consist of the tables (A, B, C, D) and (C, D, E).

There is no general rule to achieve a higher normal form. It depends on which normal form you currently have and which normal form you want to achieve. You will have to do whatever is necessary to meet the requirements of the normal form you want to achieve.